# How to use linux console in VSC windows?

Tags: c, linux, windows, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Actually there are some troubles for me to use both OS together, I already know about clion or same IDE's for C-code, but if there are possibilities to use VSC with a linux console on windows OS? I'm using mingw for build/debug, but really need to work with terminal sometimes, in particular with makefile's and stdin, and as for PowerShell it might be a little complicated.

I already have a WSL, but have no idea how to "install" linux distribution "inside" windows, if it's actually possible:)

Comment: You have to go to Windows App Store, and find ubuntu over there, install it, then you can use Ubuntu along with WSL

Comment: You don't need a WSL to get a "Linux console". Multiple ports of for example bash exist for Windows. If you happen to have installed Git for Windows, you got one already.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Linux variants for WSL [via the Microsoft Store](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/ubuntu-on-windows/9NBLGGH4MSV6?hl=en-us&gl=us), e.g. [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-10#3-download-ubuntu).

Afterwards you need to install the [WSL extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial) in VS Code, then you can open a remote development session with your WSL instance via the remote explorer tab:

[image: remote explorer]